# PHP comparing two equal double numbers raises FALSE

Tags: php

This problem drives me crazy. I have some other solution for it, but I would like top understand what is going on here, why php behaves like this in this case.

I have two MySql tables:

```
Packs:
+---------+-------------+
| Field   | Type        |
+---------+-------------+
| id      | int(11)     |
| price   | double(7,3) |
|   :     |   :         |
+---------+-------------+

Contracts:
+-------------+---------------+
| Field       | Type          |
+-------------+---------------+
| id          | int(11)       |
| final_price | decimal(20,3) |
|   :         |   :           |
+-------------+---------------+
```

I retrieve `SUM(price)` and `SUM(final_price)` into two php variables (`$totalPrice` and `$totalFinalPrice`), then I need to compare them.
When I do:

```
var_dump(
   gettype($totalPrice),
   $totalPrice,
   gettype($totalFinalPrice),
   $totalFinalPrice,
   $totalPrice == $totalFinalPrice);
```

I get:

```
string(6) "double"
float(39.669)
string(6) "string"
string(6) "39.669"
bool(false)
```

I also tried to cast both to [float](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) or to [doubleval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.doubleval), but again, although `var_dump` returns **exactly the same value**, the **comparison returns false!**

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5271114/1039488), but I doubt this is the reason in this case, since the values in the database in finite and equal.

========= UPDATE =======
It is impossible to reproduce this problem assigning directly these values into variables. Only after retrieving them from DB.

I use eloquent, here is the code:

```
$totalPrice = DB::table('Packs')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(price) AS total_price')
    ->whereIn('id_packs', [3371,3372,3373,3374])
    ->first()->total_price;

$totalFinalPrice = DB::table('Contracts')
    ->selectRaw('SUM(final_price) AS total_final_price')
    ->whereIn('id_contracts', [204028,204029,204030,204031])
    ->first()->total_final_price;

$totalPriceDouble = (double) $totalPrice;
$totalFinalPriceDouble = (double) $totalFinalPrice;

dd($totalPrice == $totalFinalPrice, $totalPriceDouble == $totalFinalPriceDouble);
```

which returns:

```
^ false
^ false
```

====== Update (2) =======
I tried to reproduce the problem with PHPize Online, here is the demo:
[https://phpize.online/s/on](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/8dabdb5a08b2c4a51a54b859fa833a17/php/php81/f2c63d5fff78883b68af84fa15ac0f87/)

I don't know why in my local machine the `var_dump` does not show the whole number, anyway this is what I see in the demo:

```
MySql:
+==========+========+
| id_packs | price  |
+==========+========+
| 3371     | 27.260 |
| 3372     | 0.000  |
| 3373     | 0.000  |
| 3374     | 12.409 |
+----------+--------+

+==============+============+
| id_contracts | FinalPrice |
+==============+============+
| 204028       | 27.260     |
| 204029       | 0.000      |
| 204030       | 0.000      |
| 204031       | 12.409     |
+--------------+------------+

PHP:
After executing queries:
 > float(39.669000000000004)
 > string(6) "39.669"
After casting into double:
 > float(39.669000000000004)
 > float(39.669)
```

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://3v4l.org/tpPrm)

Comment: It would help to see some more of the code, specifically your instantiation of PDO (assuming you're using it) and how you assign the variables. But in the end you'll want to use `bccomp()` anyway. Float arithmetic is notoriously unreliable, and not just in PHP. Especially when dealing with money, you'll want to use accurate arbitrary precision mathematics.

Comment: [The answer you saw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271058/odd-behavior-comparing-doubles-two-php-double-values-arent-equivalent/5271114#5271114) is correct, and probably the reason here as well.

Comment: it is perfectly possible to reproduce,if you use a service like https://phpize.online/

Comment: Unfortunately, your question has been closed pointing to a previous post that does not address your case. Although `$totalPrice` shows as `float(39.669)` that could very well be an approximate value. Floating point is implemented as a Base 2 number and decimal numbers in general cannot be represented precisely. Try: `$sum = 0.0; for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) $sum += .1; var_dump(gettype($sum), $sum, $sum == 1.0);`. You will get `float(1)` displayed for `$sum` but the actual value is not 1.0, i.e. `$sum == 1.00` is `bool(false)`.

Comment: I would like to contradict the statement that "Float arithmetic" is notoriously unreliable. It is only unreliable if you don't understand its limitations. If you do it works very reliable. When dealing with money many program internally use integers and convert these to decimal numbers only on output. So for US$ everything internally would work in dollar cents. Sometimes floats are even used here, to be able to work with fractions of dollar cents.